# one of 15 astronauts to have landed on Mars

Tags: to-infinitive, infinitive-clauses

Are the following sentences okay?

> a. Peter is one of 15 astronauts to have landed on Mars.

> b. Peter is an astronaut to have landed on Mars.

If there's any difference in acceptability, could you explain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(B) is not a valid sentence.

The construction *one of [a number of people] to have [done something]* has a special use when the subject of the sentence has done something unusual.

If you don't mention how many others have done it, you need only say "Peter is an astronaut who has landed on Mars."

Comment: Thank you. According to (A), have all the other 14 astronauts landed on Mars?

Comment: According to (A) there are 14 other astronauts who have landed on Mars (and there may be many other astronauts who have not landed on Mars)

Comment: "*Peter is **one** astronaut to have landed on Mars.*" This implies the others.

Comment: @gotube Are you saying "Peter is **one** astronaut to have landed on Mars" is correct? What about "Peter is **an** astronaut to have landed on Mars"?

Comment: That is not a valid sentence, which is why I suggested _who has_.

Comment: @Apollyon yes, I'm saying it's a good sentence. Kate disagrees, so take it as you will. "...is **an** astronaut..." is bad. I can't say why. Perhaps because "one" implies "one of a group" to me, where "an" does not.

Comment: @gotube - No, I meant that  _an astronaut to have_ was invalid. _One astronaut to have_ is OK - I  would expect it to be followed by _...others are X and Y_.

Comment: My mistake. Sorry and thanks